# Change the behavior of a method to use in unit Test in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

my problem is that my unit test are slow because I'm publishing in a topic in those unit test, I would like to mock or change its behavior in some way. I was thinking in use reflection for this class and change the method behavior but I'm not sure if that is possible.

This is the behavior that I like to mock or change:

```
TopicCall.builder()
        .toTopic(XXXX)
        .withAttribute(XXXXXX, XXXXX)
        .withAttribute(XXXXX, XXXXXX)
        .withAttribute(XXXXX,XXXXX)
        .publish();
```

I would like to do this because publis() is a real invocation and the test is slow and causing some problems in jenkins, because several unit test are publishing at the same time.

The Topic class is a public class with a static builder method which return a class instance, just like the next one:

```
public static TopicCall builder() {
     return new TopicCall();
}
```

My problem is that I just acceding the method of this class from outside and I'm not sending the class in the constructor as example and I'm not able to mock its behavior, I'm not able to modify the TopicCall class because it is a .class utility from a jar, besides that I'm not able to use PowerMockito or another library, just Mockito, is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to not use PowerMockito?

Comment: @VladimirShefer is a restriction of the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** *I missed the fact that PowerMock is forbidden for the author, but the answer could be useful for other users with the same problem.*

#### PowerMock

As far as you want to mock a static method, then Mockito is not the solution.

This could be done using [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock).

PowerMock uses `ClassLoader` way for mocking, which could significantly increase tests time to run.

Here is an [examle on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock#methods) how to mock static methods.

---

Solution scratch:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ TopicCall.class })
public class Test {
  
  @Test
  void test() {
    mockStatic(TopicCall.class);
    when(TopicCall.builder()).thenReturn(/*value to be returned*/ null);
    
    // the test code...

  }

}
```

Comment: I said that I'm not allowed to use PowerMockito. Thanks!

Comment: @rasilvap, my bad. this note is invisible in the wall of the text. Could you please edit the question and highlight this requirement?